# What would be the request body during post data from fiddler

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

For simple web API data posting what would be the request body where my code behind code is :
`string strValue = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["strValue"].ToString();`

I'm here to know if i want to post data using fiddler what would be the request body format(i've try json and xml but it doesn't work for it) and what would be the content type in header.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the relevant documentation for [HttpRequest.Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: @mason Yes, I've already with json and xml format but it didn't worked.

Comment: i think for HttpContext.Current.Request.Form you have to send it as form-x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: The documentation doesn't mention anything about JSON or XML because those have nothing to do with `HttpRequest.Form`. It does however mention `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so you should go learn about what that means.

Comment: Yes Content-Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded but what would be the request body format?

Comment: Go research what it means to have a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as that will tell you how to structure the body.